# Create new table from existing with all non duplicate and only last (largest primary key) duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a new table from existing table with same columns. But problem is my existing table has duplicate rows. I want to insert all the data from the table to new table but with only one record from duplicate rows.

For example :

```
id        name       other
 1         Test1      User
 2         Test1      User
 3         Test2      User2
```

I want id 2,3 in new table.
hope i make you understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
create table newtable as
    select max(id) as id, name, other
    from t
    group by name, other;
```

Or, if you have many columns:

```
create table newtable as
    select t.*
    from t
    where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

EDIT:

From comments, the OP's final query is:

```
create table new_tester
    select t.* 
    from tester t
    where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
                  from tester t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.other = t.other
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked, i also used this query with != to get the records which are not included in this result.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help everybody

Here is the full query :

create table new_tester as 
select t.*
from tester t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from tester t2 where t2.name = t.name AND t2.other =  t.other);

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
create table newTable as 
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where name = t.name and other = t.other and id > t.id
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bTAgDFL4W6eukjegpGLVBz/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name  | other |
| --- | ----- | ----- |
| 2   | Test1 | User  |
| 3   | Test2 | User2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement:

```
create table testTable2 
as 
select distinct name
              , other 
from testTable;
```

Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1097f05365cca9b0c96c805f1db1c794)

Or if you want to have an ID also in the new table I recommend a new number:

```
create table teatTable2 as 
select row_number() over (order by name) id
       , name
       , other 
from
(select distinct name, other from testTable) as t1;
```

Comment: i have multiple columns to compare to find duplicate so i can't use distinct